# Find point given angle and two points

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I have the following problem. I have tried searching through some previous articles but most were written problems without visuals and I could not follow to know if this has been asked before (I'm sure it has).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I need to solve the value of y in the following diagram:

[Image for reference (embedding isn't available for me...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd8dF.png)

Comment: I've tried reading through the Wikipedia article on [Solutions of triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_triangles) and also googling of solutions but a lot seem to be complex with mathematical notation. I am not that well educated at trigonometry. I am trying to work out this point for a visualization I am making rather than for study or exams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received a solution from another forum.

Here it is for posterity:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q1ac.png)

Comment: Right corner point coordinates (400,400).

Comment: Yes, the right corner point is incorrectly labelled. Thanks for pointing it out!